# How can i send included the .ics file PHP

Tags: php, outlook, appointment

The objective of the code is to generate an outlook appointment and send to people. Currently i have a code able to generate .ics file.

```
    <?php

$startTime ='12-15-2015';
$endTime='12-15-2015';
$subject='Test';
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "example.com
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:".$date."T".$startTime."00Z
DTEND:".$date."T".$endTime."00Z
SUMMARY:".$subject."
DESCRIPTION:".$desc."
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

  //set correct content-type-header
  header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
  echo $ical;
  exit;
?>
```

When this code is trigger, the .ics file will download into user computer. User will need to manually click the .ics file then the outlook will pop up. 
Can i have something, when i trigger the code, the outlook will auto open up with those start and end date?

Thank You

Comment: No, this can only be configured on the client. There is nothing you can do on a server to influence this.

Comment: No. What if Outlook is not installed on the client side? You cannot handle client side behavior from the server code.

Comment: Is that mean i only can generate the .ics file and attach into the email content?